# Prime ng tree table resizer is not working in expand mode when virtual is scroll and scrollable true

Tags: angular, primeng-datatable, primeng-table, primeng-treetable, primeng-tree

I am using prime ng tree table Resizr and also prime ng tree table virtual scroll but when I use column resize mode in expand mode it's not work properly as expand mode does, but when I off the virtual scroll and scrollable then its worksk fine.

Note: the resizr is working, but when you adjusting a column  previous column is also adjut with it,but virtual scroll is off then its work smooth.

```
<p-treeTable id="listViewTree" [value]="scheduledWorkItems" [columns]="cols" [resizableColumns]="true" columnResizeMode="expand" 
  scrollHeight="flex" [virtualScroll]="true" [virtualRowHeight]="34.25" 
     (onNodeExpand)="onNodeExpand($event)" (onNodeCollapse)="onNodeCollapse($event)" (onColResize)="handleColResize($event)" >
     
<ng-template pTemplate="colgroup" let-columns>
      <colgroup>
           <col width="50px" >
        <col width="20px" >
        <col width="20px">
        <col width="20px">
        <col width="20px">
      </colgroup>
      
      
  </ng-template>

    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of cols" ttResizableColumn>
                {{ col.name }}
            </th>           
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowNode let-rowData="rowData" let-columns="columns">
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns; let i = index">
                <p-treeTableToggler [rowNode]="rowNode" *ngIf="i === 0"></p-treeTableToggler>
                {{ rowData[col.name] }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-treeTable>
```